# Less bitcoin recived in zebpay

Tags: coinbase.com

My friend transferred 0.00369135 BTC from coinbase to my zebpay , but i received only 0.0028 BTC . Why the difference in numbers ?

Please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That can be the transaction fee charged. Do the calculation according to the Zebpay guide and validate the received amount.

E.g when you sell/transfer bitcoin to a different address, a transaction fee is charged.

Quoted from zebpay.
[Zebpay transaction fees on selling bitcoins](https://zebpay.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205037111-What-are-Zebpay-s-fee-and-charges-)

"You will be charged a bitcoin network fee when you send bitcoins to a bitcoin address depending on the number of bitcoins you send. Fees are dynamic and updated on daily basis. Please check your app for latest fees.